# Replace last comma using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, slice

http://jsbin.com/uxepap/3/edit

Here is div with links inside. I'm trying to replace comma inside last `<a>` with point "."

This comma comes from numeral sort of the list, should be replaced with point.

The problem is, all links stored inside `links` var, not sure how to get the last one and then replace it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.replace`

```
var links = $('a');

var $last = links.filter(":last");

$last.html( $last.html().replace(",", "."));
```

http://jsbin.com/uxepap/5/edit

Answer (score 2):

```
links.eq(-1).html(function(index, value) {
  return value.replace(/,\s*$/, ".");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/uxepap/7/edit

Comment: I like your answer better, but is more difficult to understand for n00bies. Which is why I made a simplistic one. :)

Comment: @Trevor OK, the logic is pretty simple. `eq(-1)` takes the last element, function in `html()` returns value, where `replace` method with regular expression replaces *the last comma only*, whereas simple `replace(",", ".")` will replace the first comma even if it will be inside the link tag.

Comment: I understand it, but others may not. It's a better answer than mine, but someone who is not familiary with `regex` and JS in general will have difficulty with it. I figured, since his demo only had one comma in it, it was okay to a replace with string literals.

Comment: @Trevor Well, now I have [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774713/replace-last-comma-using-jquery/10774733#comment14010485_10774733) to clarify the logic :)